# iPad/iPhone AnyConnect VPN wrong MTU size

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, vpn, unix

I try to connect with a iPad (iOS 5.1) and the AnyConnect app to connect to a OpenVPN server on a Debian server. But this warning always appears in the OpenVPN log:

> WARNING: Bad encapsulated packet length from peer (5635), which must
>   be > 0 and <= 1560 -- please ensure that --tun-mtu or --link-mtu is
>   equal on both peers

On the server side the tun interface mtu size is 1500 bytes.
I can connect with other clients (pcs, macs, ...) to the server. But with a iPad or iPhone client this warning appears and no connection is established.

How can I fix this?

Br

Comment: Hmm, from what I can see AnyConnect doesn't support OpenVPN servers at all?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to set the MTU on iOS. There is no GUI for it, and without jailbreaking you can't access the `ifconfig` command line tool that would be used to configure this on OS X (I think `ifconfig` might not exist anyway even if you do jailbreak).

I have the same problem with a VPN I use occasionally. To use it with OS X I have to run `sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1270`. From iOS there is no solution, however I've noticed VLC clients seem to work fine even with a broken MTU and am able to access the office network that way.

To fix this, you're going to have to configure your server somehow - that would be a good question for [Serve Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Comment: I think it does exist, I've used it a few time on my iPad. But command line network utilities on iOS devices is quite crappy.

Comment: @ShaneHsu do you have any example of such tool?